# Не передаётся аргумент cmd

Tags: c#, cmd

```
var cmdstring = "explorer Shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}";


System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

startInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Comment: да, Вашим кодом не передается никакой параметр

Comment: Я не силён в C#, но чтобы `cmd.exe` кого-то запустил, ему нужен ключ `/K`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой способ сделать то, что вам нужно, такой:

```
Process.Start("Shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}");
```

ну или

```
var process = Process.Start("Shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}");
```

если вам нужно ещё взаимодействие с процессом.

---

Если запускать через `cmd`, нужен ключ `/c` (и нужно отделить команду от аргументов):

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/c explorer Shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}");
```

Comment: Нужно больше посредников! Предлагаю запускать вот так: `Process.Start("cmd", "/c powershell -c explorer \\^\"Shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}\\^\");`

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Мало посредников! На Windows 10 ещё есть bash!